# EntityFramework 5 and Projection / Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have the following EF 5.0 entities:

```
public class Pack {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
} // Pack

public class File {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Byte[] Data { get; set; }
} // File
```

With a generic repository I need to get ONE pack and its files IDs but not the data.

On my generic repository I have the following method:

```
public T First<T>(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> criteria) where T : class {
  return _context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(criteria);
} // First
```

I am getting the Pack and mapping to the PackDtoModel as follows:

```
Pack pack = _repository.First<Pack>(x => x.Id == packId);

PackDtoModel model = new PackDtoModel  {
  Id = pack.Id,
  FilesIds = pack.Files.Select(x => x.Id).ToList()
}
```

**Is this loading the File Data fields? I do not want that!**

Should I use a projection to avoid loading the Files data?

If yes, how? The first method returns a T and not an IQueryable.

I am using Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true ...

Using table splitting I could use the following:

```
create table dbo.Packs
(
  Id int identity not null
    constraint Packs_Id_PK primary key clustered (Id)
);

create table dbo.Files
(
  Id int not null
    constraint Files_Id_PK primary key clustered (Id),
  Data varbinary (max) filestream null
    constraint Files_Data_DF default (0x),  
  [Key] uniqueidentifier rowguidcol not null
    constraint Files_Key_U unique,      
  Mime nvarchar (200) not null,
    CONSTRAINT Files_ID_Mime_UQ UNIQUE (Id, Mime) 
) filestream_on [STORAGE];

add constraint Files_Id_FK foreign key (Id) references dbo.Packs(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade;
```

So the File ID is same as the Pack ID.

And I added a constraint so that a File ID and MIME would be unique.

So now in my application I would use: GET FILE WITH ID = PACKID & MIME = "image/jpg".

The moment I get the pack I know the id of the files associated with that pack.

I need only to specify which version (mime) I want ...

What do you think?

My problem now is how to map this to Entities ...

In theory I should still have many files in a pack:

```
public class Pack {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
} // Pack
```

But how to set this relation?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Take a look at [Table Splitting](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/24/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting.aspx).

Comment: Yes, that is the point ... I am doing it. My files table is spited from the Pack table. But when I display a pack in the page I need to know the IDS of the files to call so I can render the files urls in the page ... So what are you suggesting?

Comment: You are and you aren't. With table splitting one table is split over several entities, usually to prevent (lazy) loading of part of an entity. You just have a 1:n association. But you're right: there is not much left to split. You can do `_repository.Files.Where(f => f.Id == pack.Id).Select(x => x.Id)` to get the ids only. `pack.Files` will query `Data` as well.

Comment: Hello, I see what you mean. I tried to change my schema to avoid getting the ids. Basically, I now know the File ID is the same as its Pack ID. I get files by ID and Mime. Can I integrate that into a EF?